# Exibir Conteúdo Datetime usando Doctrine

Tags: php, web-service, doctrine, slim

Em um projeto de WebService usando o SlimFramework, resolvi adicionar o Doctrine para fazer as consultas no BD.
Resolvi seguir a orientação do DOCTRINE para trabalhar com Datetime e Fusos Horários segundo esse site [Doctrine Documentação](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/working-with-datetime.html)

Ao tentar recuperar o valor do banco usei o seguinte código:

```
  try{
    $repository = $entityManager->getRepository(User::class);
    $usuarios = $repository->findAll();

    foreach ($usuarios as $usuario){
        var_dump( $usuario->getUserDthActivation()) .  "<br/>";
    }
    die;
    return $response
        ->withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
        ->write(json_encode($usuarios, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
}catch (Exception $e){

}
```

O resultado impresso foi o seguinte:

> object(DateTimeZone)#138 (2) { ["timezone_type"]=> int(3)
>   ["timezone"]=> string(17) "America/Sao_Paulo" } object(DateTime)#140
>   (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2012-07-01 08:36:35.000000"
>   ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(17)
>   "America/Sao_Paulo" }

No meu caso eu preciso apenas da informação **01-07-2012 08:07:35**

Qual é a maneira correta para exibir apenas o conteúdo da data no formato dd-mm-YY hh:mm:ss?

O arquivo que faz esse tratamento é o seguinte:

```
class UTCDateTimeType extends DateTimeType
{
/** @var \DateTimeZone */
static private $utc = null;

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
{
    if ($value === null) {
        return null;
    }

    if (!$value instanceof \DateTime) {
        return null;
    }

    $value->setTimezone((self::$utc) ? self::$utc : (self::$utc = new \DateTimeZone('UTC')));

    return $value->format($platform->getDateTimeFormatString());
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
{

    if ($value === null) {
        return null;
    }

    $val = \DateTime::createFromFormat(
        $platform->getDateTimeFormatString(),
        $value,
        (self::$utc) ? self::$utc : (self::$utc = new \DateTimeZone('UTC'))
    );

    if (!$val) {
        throw ConversionException::conversionFailed($value, $this->getName());
    }

    return $val;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se `$usuario->getUserDthActivation()` retornar um [***DateTime***](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.datetime.php) válido, você pode melhorar o retorno fazendo assim:

```
$usuario->getUserDthActivation()->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');
```

**Referencia:**

- [***DateTime***](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.datetime.php)
- [***DateTime::format***](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.format.php)

Comment: Ao fazer isso ele trouxe o seguinte resultado:  object(DateTimeZone)#138 (2) { ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(17) "America/Sao_Paulo" } 01-07-2012 08:07:35  Como eu poderia pegar apenas a data e excluir o restante das informações?

Comment: @IsraelZebulon ao fazer o que?

Comment: Ao executar o comando: $usuario->getUserDthActivation()->format('d-m-Y H:i:s'); exibiu o conteúdo acima. Mas o que desejo é apenas parte dessa informção. No caso quero saber qual o modo correto para recuperar apenas a data/hora.

Comment: @IsraelZebulon, certeza absoluta, porque na frente a data está formatada, poderia ver seu código. Tanto é que olha o fim do `var_dump` `01-07-2012 08:07:35` a data foi formatada !!! como está usando o código que deve ser o problema!

Comment: Sim, a data formatou , agora ao executar o comando, o sistema não deveria trazer apenas a data ao invés de trazer toda essa informação adicional?  Vou editar a pergunta e postar o código que executa essa formatação.

Comment: @IsraelZebulon tem uma edição, me parece que vem dois objetos então acesse o número 1 e formate com a opção que eu coloquei!

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45715/discussion-between-virgilio-novic-and-israel-zebulon).